# RXSwift: Catch an error without emiting an element from the stream

Tags: rx-swift

Ultimately I need a way to catch RXSwift errors without emitting another item to the stream, this doesn't seem possible with the current RX operators.

Here's how my application works now:

I have 3 layers:

- Service layer
- Local data layer
- Remote data layer

The service layer acts as a bridge between the local and remote layers and is called directly by UI code.

For each function provided in the service layer e.g. `getData() -> Observable<String>` I need to do the following:

- Get the local data & start a ticker counting from 0 upwards every second
- Get the data from the remote service
- The ticker should only complete when the remote service completes
- If the local service returns an error, it must be ignored and not emitted
- When the remote service completes, update the local data with the new data, if any

I've gotten this far in a playground:

The local data service:

```
let localService = Observable<String>.create { (observer) -> Disposable in
    observer.onNext("Local result")
    observer.onCompleted()
    return Disposables.create()
}.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
```

The remote data service:

```
let remoteService = Observable<String>.create { (observer) -> Disposable in
    observer.onNext("Remote result")
    observer.onCompleted()
    return Disposables.create()
}.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance).delay(5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
```

The database updater service:

```
let databaseUpdaterService = Observable<Void>.empty().observeOn(MainScheduler.instance).delay(2, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
let remoteAndDatabaseService = remoteService.do(onNext: { (value) in
    print("Database updating")
    _ = databaseUpdaterService.subscribe(onCompleted: {
        print("Database updated")
    })
})
```

The time ticker:

```
let ticker = Observable<Int>.interval(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).do(onNext: { (tick) in
    print("Ticker event: \(tick) seconds")
}).takeUntil(remoteService)
```

The merged service:

```
let mergedService = Observable<String>.merge([localService, remoteAndDatabaseService])
```

Starting the ticker:

```
print("Ticker start")
_ = ticker.subscribe(onError: { (error) in
    print("Ticker error")
}, onCompleted: {
    print("Ticker completed")
}, onDisposed: {
    print("Ticker disposed")
})
```

Starting the service:

```
print("Service start")
_ = mergedService.subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
    print("Service value: \(value)")
}, onError: { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}, onCompleted: {
    print("Service completed")
}, onDisposed: {
    print("Service disposed")
})
```

For the happy path, this works perfectly.

However, in the case where the localService calls an `onError` (if the local object doesn't exist for example) the merged stream terminates.

I would like for the error to be swallowed up and for nothing to be emmitted by the stream for the localService.

Currently the `catch` operators force you to emit another object instead of failing silently.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to bring in the whole RxSwiftExt library for just one thing you can use `.catchError { _ in Observable.empty() }` which will eat the error and emit a complete event.

Another option is `.catchError { _ in Observable.never() }` which will eat the error and then emit nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,

Looks like RxSwiftExt has the following method that works for my use case: `catchErrorJustComplete() -> Observable<E>`